# Does the Torah acknowledge that there are various types of fasts: dry fasts, water fasts, and perhaps others?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, fast-days, water

Generally, when observant Jews think about *fasting*, they think about the dry fasting done on the 9th of Av or Yom Kippur, in which we neither eat nor drink. This is related to the idea of rising above the physical/material plane of existence.

In the context of a one-day fast, or even a two-day fast, dry fasting is doable, but also puts some stress on the body.

Conversely, in the context of making a *tikkun* over past transgressions, the number of fasts prescribed in Torah is often many more days than simply a day or two. See for example the references in the Tanya in Igeret HaTeshuvah at [the end of chapter 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49432&st=&pgnum=183) to Sefer Rokeach and Mishnat Chassidim and also in [chapter 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49432&st=&pgnum=185) there.

Medically speaking, water fasting, meaning abstinence from eating, is something that can be done for many, many days consecutively. *The world record for fasting is [over a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angus_Barbieri%27s_fast).* However, a dry fast (abstinence from both eating and drinking) can only be survived for three to five days. The abstinence from water is the critical factor.

**Does the Torah make a distinction between types of fasts?** The Aramaic word for *fast* is תענית from the Hebrew ענה. The Hebrew root has a connotation of *to respond* or *to answer* (as in answering for improper actions) and also *to deprive*, or *to delay*, or *to submit/become humble* or *to become poor*. All of these relate to the idea of depriving oneself of food in humility and an act of submission to G-d's will.

The consequence being that one burns their excess body fat, which is compared to burning the fat of an offering on the altar brought in the Temple, like is mentioned in the Tanya for example.

So the focus seems to be about the burning of body fat, which relates to the eating of food only.

Comment: Where does the Torah prescribe fasts for more than a day or two?

Comment: @Alex Per your request...

Comment: I feel you dig deep but couldn't understand the question. The only Taanit from Torah is Y"K which is commanded as תענו את נפשתיכם hence תענית, nothing to do with answer. So what "types" you're talking about? You HAVE to make a clear distinction between the Torah and any of its interpretations, especially very recent ones.

Comment: @AlBerko I take it from your comment, "The only Taanit from Torah is Y"K", that you hold that the book of Esther is not part of the Torah. Esther 4:3 specifically mentions fasting in the context that I am using it and it wasn't Yom Kippur. To clarify for you, fasting can involve food or water or both. Consider the distinction between רעב and צמא. Abstaining from water doesn't result in fat burning. The burning of body fat (the objective of fasting תענית) is only a consequence of abstaining from food.

Comment: @Yaacov Most Jews indeed hold the book of Esther is not part of the Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Only if you are limiting your definition of "Torah" to the five books of Moshe. And most Jews use the undelineated expression 'Torah' generically to include all of the written and oral Torah, unless they specifically point out otherwise.

Comment: It's all about context @Yaacov. In my experience, you use the word "Torah" differently from most Jews. There was no ambiguity in AlBerko's comment to most Jews.

Comment: Indeed, my above comment did not assume that “prescribed in Torah” meant the Tanya. Cc @DoubleAA

Comment: I think the fact of fat *burning* wasn't known until very recently. You can't base your claim on last century knowledge.

Comment: @Alex Try reading the 2 links I provided to the Tanya. The Alter Rebbe cites Rabbi Emanuel Chai Riki (Acharon) and also the Rokeach (Rishon) as well as Esther from Tanach. I could have used other non-Chassidic sources. It was simply convenient.

Comment: @AlBerko It's Berakhot 17 ועכשיו ישבתי בתענית ונתמעט חלבי ודמי

Comment: @DoubleAA Esp. ודמי. And what's וחלבי?

Comment: @AlBerko my milk? :)  What's unclear? Ancients were definitely aware that fat people who ate very little became thin.

Comment: I understood (can't remember from where) that these fasts done in the context of making a _tikkun_ over past transgressions, were meant to be _Ta'aniyot_ like the other three fasts over the destruction of the Temple, and _Ta'anit Ester_, that are from _Amud ha-Shachar_ till _Tzet ha-Kokhavim_ (that one can eat and drink the night before), rather than like _Yom Kippur_ or _Tish'ah be-Av_ that last [over] 24 hours. It could be what your second link refers to, when it says ([a few pages later](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49432&pgnum=187)): "ויכול לדחותן לימים הקצרים בחורף ...".

Comment: Do these fasts need to be consecutive? Maybe they can be spread out so it's not impossible to do

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Rabbeinu Yona in Sod Hateshuva brings an inyan about what's become referred to as "taanis HaRaavad" which is to refrain from a little bit of eating.

I couldn't find it online so I attached a picture. I don't think it's exactly what you were looking for, but it's close.

Comment: Source of Raavad is at the end of his sefer on Hilchos Mikvaos. Interestingly, he also advises eating tasty food so that one will be satisfied with less.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking if there is a concept of fasting from food without refraining from water in Torah.

I would suggest that a צום could be refraining only from food but allowing water.  In Ester 5:16 and Yona 3:5-7 not eating and not drinking are specified, which would seem to imply that there could be a tzom not like that. Also in Shmuel II chapter 12, Dovid is tzome, and only food is mentioned, not drink.

This is not conclusive; please don't complain about that.

Comment: Not complaining & thanks for trying.   Fasting is refraining from eating and drinking (food-something you benefit from). But ‘benefit’ in Torah has a particular meaning. This is discussed in Shulchan Aruch and elsewhere. That’s why we make blessings on pleasant scents too. Torah considers them to be a kind of spiritual food (less material than for example, bread and wine). And water, which has neither taste nor scent, is in a unique category. No surprise that Torah, at least part of it, is compared to water.