# If you're well-hydrated at the start of a fast, can you keep drinking water throughout the fast? If not, why not?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, water, drinking

Generally speaking, when the Torah is discussing the concept of fasting, whether on individual fasts or public fasts, it mentions the prohibition of *neither eating, nor drinking*.

But water has a special status in terms of being considered in the category of a  *drink*.

Water has no taste or scent which appears to be the physical distinction delineated in Torah (halacha) as found for example in [Shulchan Aruch HaRav,volume 1, 202:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=602) (citing the [Turay Zahav to Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim, 205:2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.205.2?lang=bi&with=Turei%20Zahav&lang2=en)).

And in fact, like is mentioned in [Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Birchot HaNehanin, Chapter 1, halacha 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=666) that according to the Sofrim all eating and drinking requires a blessing beforehand *if one benefits/takes pleasure* in it.

And yet, water does not receive a blessing before it or after it because it has no taste or scent, unless one is drinking from being *parched*. If one is not parched, water is not considered to be a drink *in the halachic sense*. Like is mentioned in [Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Birchot HaNehanin, Chapter 10:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=695). If one is not parched, then no blessing is made. This is in spite of the fact that one swallows it.

And this leads to the question.

If one is properly hydrated prior to the commencement of a fast, private or public, so that they are not parched, is it permitted to drink water intermittently throughout the fast? Is it still considered to be fulfilling the mitzvah?

This is assuming that one abstains from all eating and drinking of all other beverages.

If not, why not. Please provide clear sources.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109259/759

Comment: Interesting, but I think it's a questionable inferrence that water is only considered a drink when it's consumed in thirst. Birchos Hanehenin requires bodily enjoyment; maybe fasting doesn't. We don't avoid rinsing our mouths out of fear of swallowing without a bracha.